# REST URL design for greater than, less than operations

Tags: rest, url

I am having a bit of difficulty designing a url for a rest service that can handle requests for customers based on pagination as one type of operation or requesting greater than or less than operators as another type of operation.  For example:

**Pagination:**

```
GET /customers/0/100
```

This will get 100 customers for page 0.

**Greater/Less Than:**

I also need a URL design to get customers that have an id greater than n (e.g. lets say 716).  How would you incorporate "greater than" or "less than" in a url. I have to bear in mind that characters ">" and "<" are illegal in urls.  I think this url design looks odd:

```
GET /customers/greaterthan/716
GET /customers/lessthan/716
```

I can't use a range as that would conflict with the pagination pattern specified above and is not a nice solution in any case e.g.:

```
GET /customers/716/999999999999
GET /customers/0/716
```

I'm sure that I'm missing something obvious - does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: how do you plan to implement this in real time scenario--just for curiosity

Comment: it's being done using the Restlet framework in Java.  Essentially, I'm querying a database for records.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

*Pagination*, *greaterthan* and *lessthan*, sound like query parameter to me, since you are queries your resource with these parameters. So you should do something like:

**/customers?page=1**, or
**/customers?page=1&gt=716**, or
**/customers?page=1&gt=716&lt=819**

You can even limit size of page:

**/customers?page=1&gt=716&lt=819&maxpagesize=100**

where *gt* stands for greater than (same as in xml-escaping) and *lt* stands for less than.

Comment: sorry I think I've confused everyone here - I don't mean do pagination and more than, less than operations all at the same time.  Pagination is a separate function and the less/greater than is another type of function.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Pagination and less/greater are unrelated issues. You should identify your resource. In your case the resource is customers. Both pagination and less/greater are query on the resource, but it's still the same resource. Therefore you should not try to insert your functionality in the url (path-param), but instead you should use query params. At the end your call will reach the same resource class (in java), than you can add your query params to the SQL query or something like this.

Comment: Even if you put the params in the query string, you are still referring to a different resource.  That's ok though.  Two different resources can still render portions of the same underlying dataset.  Simple rule:  If it's a different URL and it doesn't redirect then it is a different resource.

Comment: also, you should make sure your query string params are always in the same order (assuming they are independent), otherwise /resource?a=1&b=2 is a different resource from /resource?b=2&a=1 and a cached entry for one cannot be returned for the other

Comment: It seems Tarlog has provided a good solution here however others might find this a useful resource for API design and practice... http://apigee.com/about/api-best-practices/all/webcast

Comment: Why gt/lt instead of symbols? (<>)

Comment: <> are special characters.

Answer (score 29):

If you have multiple parameters and need to apply some conditions for each params, I recommend you to pass a JSON object to params.

Consider you want to do a condition for `id` and the `page`:

```
/customers?id={"lt": 100, "gt": 30}&page={"start": 1, "size": 10}
```

It says that I want customers that have Id(s) **less than** 100 and **greater than** 30 in the **page** 1  and **page number** of 10.

So now simply if you want to apply another condition for other parameters, you can do it by:

```
/customers?id={"lt": 100, "gt": 30}&children={"lt": 5, "gt": 2}&page={"start": 1, "size": 10}
```

and this query means customers with Id(s) **less than** 100 and **greater than** 30, children **less than** 5 and **greater than** 2 in the **page number** 1 with **page size** of 10.

I highly recommend you to read this document about designing RESTful API: http://blog.luisrei.com/articles/rest.html

Answer (score 15):

Here is how I have been doing it.

Let's say you have the field **age** which is a number.

This is what the urls would look like
Equals: /filter/age=5 
Greater Than: /filter/age[gt]=5 
Greater Than Equals: /filter/age[gte]=5 
Less Than: /filter/age[lt]=5 
Less Than Equals: /filter/age[lte]=5 
Not Equals: /filter/age[ne]=5

Then when I pass these arguments to the back-end I have a script that just parses the key out and converts it to the correct filter based on the age[INSERT_OPERATOR_HERE]

Comment: I like this approach the most. It's clear and uses only one parameter.

Answer (score 10):

@Julio Faerman:

> Well, the problem starts when you get multiple parameters. Imagine the query string for "Customers older than 18 and younger than 60 with more than 2 children".

You can define whatever query parameters you like, such as:

```
/customers?min-age=19&max-age=59&min-children=3
```

in my example min and max are integers and are inclusive. You can change that if you prefer. Remember, anything in the URI connotes part of the resource identifier. My personal view is that things after the `?` equate to clauses in the `WHERE` part of an SQL query (plus `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`, not shown here):

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE age>=19 AND age<=59 AND children>=3
```

**Edit:**
Instead of `min-` and `max-` prefixes, you could allow `>`, `<` (and maybe `!`) as the final character of the parameter name, so instead of `min-age` you have a parameter called `age>`, which, when combined with a value in the query string, ends up looking like `age>=19` :-)
Obviously you can only use this trick when the comparison has an equals sign in it.

Comment: Seems most reliable way to stick with rest! If they use json in query - then way better to go for mongo query style and POST with x-method-override = get. Otherwise everything arrived after "?" - referred as filtering options.

Comment: @ValentinRusk I didn't understand that. Can you re-post it in your first language so I can translate myself? Ты русский?

Comment: Лучший выбор для REST !!! Если использовать JSON в GET, тогда лучше идти по пути стиля Mongo Query + header: x-method-override.  В первом случае, все что приходит после "?" - считается фильтрами.

Comment: @ValentinRusk Okay, not a question, just a compliment :-) Спасибо!

Answer (score 7):

REST is an architectural style that should not be considered as specific to HTTP.  The pattern of the URIs are not what makes an architecture RESTful.

With that said, you probably would want to make your URI so that these queries come as query parameters at the end of the string, e.g.

```
/customers?min=0&max=76
```

Comment: How would you do greater than 76?

Comment: I would think these parameters could be optional, you could just put a 'min' parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Some REST-based standarts offer adequate approaches to this problem. For example, https://www.hl7.org/fhir/stu3/search.html

Your problem can be solved like that:
`GET /customers?id=ge500&id=lt1000`

Also, there's [OData](http://www.odata.org/documentation/) which is far more interoperable that any industry-level standard. And it proposes this style: `GET /customers?$filter=id ge 500 and id lt 1000`

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you are going to fetch your server logs and suppose that your data looks like this:

```
{
    "protocol": "http",
    "host": "example.domain.com",
    "path": "/apis/classified/server/logs",
    "method": "GET",
    "ip": "::ffff:127.0.0.1",
    "time": 1483066346338,
    "usingTime": 12,
    "status": 200,
    "headers": {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 Chrome"
    }
}
```

And you want to query like this way, where

- `protocol` equals `'http'`.
- `host` equals `'example.domain.com'`, or not equals `'example.domain.me'`.
- `path` equals `'/apis/classified/server/logs'`, or likes `/*classified\/server*/`.
- `method` equals `'DELETE'` or not equals `'GET'` or in `['POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE']`.
- `ip` equals `'127.0.0.1'`, or not equals `'127.0.0.1'`.
- `usingTime` is greater than `3500`, or is greater than or equal to `1500` and less than or equal to `3500`.
- `status` equals `404`, or not equals `200`, or is greater than or equal to `400` and is less than 500.
- `headers.user-agent` likes `/*chrome*/i`.

Here the routes go like this:

- `/apis/classified/server/logs?path=/apis/classfied`
- `/apis/classified/server/logs?path.regex=*classfied*`
- `/apis/classified/server/logs?method.ne=GET`
- `/apis/classified/server/logs?method=POST&method=PATCH&method=PUT`
- `/apis/classified/server/logs?usingTime.gte=1500&usingTime.lte=2500`
- `/apis/classified/server/logs?headers.user-agent.regex=*chrome*`

If you are using express.js as the server, your req.query will be structured like:

- `{"path": "/apis/classfied"}`
- `{"path": {"regex": "*classfied*"}}`
- `{"method": "DELETE"}`
- `{"method": ["GET","POST","PUT"]}`
- `{"usingTime": {"gte": "1500","lte": "2500"}}` (lte: is less than or equal to)
- `{"status": {"ne": "200"}}}`  (ne: is Not Equal to)
- `{"path": {"regex": "*classfied*"}}`
- `{"headers": {"user-agent": {"regex": "*chrome*", "flag": "i"}}}`

And you are gonna use a lot of if-else to make up your mongoose query method, or SQL string maybe.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use querystring.

And I suggest one of the following templates:

```
?amount=~gt~100&age=~gt~16

?amount=gt100&age=gt16

?amount=gt 100&age=gt 16

?amount=greater_than(1)&age=less_than(69)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would implement it as a range, and if either side is open, just do not fill it.

```
GET /customers/16-
GET /customers/-716
```

When requesting all customers, do not add all, just leave it empty

```
GET /customers
```

Or, when you need - signs in your number/code, use this:

```
GET /customers/16/
GET /customers//716
GET /customers/16/716
```

You can escape the forward slashes if they are part of the number.

Comment: I stumbled across this today. What an elegant solution. Unfortunately, it only works for IDs, not for queries, so `/customers/16-25` is fine, because we *know* that the '-' indicates a range, but if it were query field, it wouldn't work: `/customers?name=123-127` is that customers where the value of name is from 123 to 127, or customers who have the name equals the string "123-127"? No way to tell.

Comment: I like this answer. Also check tiny range module for nodejs ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiny-range ) , you can use this notation as well : ~1,2,3,5~10,20~

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a url in postman

```
{{base_url}}/movies/filter?duration[gte]=169&ratings[lte]=9&releaseYear[gt]=2010
```

will give

```
{
  duration: { gte: '169' },
  ratings: { lte: '9' },
  releaseYear: { gt: '2010' }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

### **WARNING: Read disclaimer below**

I dont know if this quetion is related to c#. But if you are using linq for your queries on the server side, I have another suggestion:

```
GET /customers?filter=CustomerNo>=16 AND CustomerNo<=716
```

Then, on the server side:

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;

var filteredCustomers = myCustomerTable.Where(filter);
```

This should be the most flexible solution of all, I think.

---

**WARNING added january 19, 2017
It has just come to my attention that a code injection exploit exists for Dynamic Linq. The example above opens up the possibility that the client can start code execution on the server.**

Comment: It looks like an `GET /database?query=SELECT * FROM customers WHERE CustomerNo>=16 AND CustomerNo<=716` endpoint.

Answer (score -3):

I'd take

```
 GET /customers/greaterthan=16;lessthan=716/
```

as the order is not important. You can even paginate on top:

```
 GET /customers/greaterthan=16;lessthan=716/page/10
```

Alternatively (with an appropriate Request router):

```
 GET /customers/16-716/page/10
```

And without "filter":

```
 GET /customers/all/page/10
```