# REST url for resource collection, which filters resource by attribute not equal to a given value

Tags: url, rest

How to design REST url for resource collection, which filters resource by attribute not equal to a given value?

For example, to get the students in 8th grade, we use

```
GET /students?grade=8
```

How to do the same, if we need to get the students **not** in 8th grade? And how to design for less than (`<`) , greater than (`>`) etc ?

Comment: check if this link is helpful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614255/rest-url-design-for-greater-than-less-than-operations

Comment: But, it talks more about pagination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to add an additional query parameter such as `gradeOperator` in which you could pass the operator to be used when comparing the value against the `grade` parameter. E.g.,

```
GET /students?grade=8&gradeOperator=!%3D
```

`!%3D` is the [URL-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) form of `!=`, so your REST API would de-encode the operator and interpret this as `grade != 8`.

Another approach would be to pass the value and operator in the HTTP request body. Something like this would potentially work (with the body provided in JSON as an example):

```
GET /students
Content-Type: application/json

{ "grade": {"value": 8, "operator": "!=" } }
```

That could be nice since you wouldn't have to repeat the word 'grade' in `gradeOperator`, the operator is simply nested inside a JSON object as the value of `grade`.

In either solution, you could potentially define any number of operators, including `<`, `>`, `>=`, `<=`, etc. Just be sure to properly sanitize any input operators your API receives, especially if used in a DB query, to avoid things like [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Note that you should *not* use GET request bodies. It's not recommended and HTTP client, server and proxy implementations might drop it at will. GET request bodies are semantically meaningless.

Answer (score 10):

What I am thinking of doing is including the operator as part of the argument, delimited from the value. I would also define non-symbolic operators to avoid the need for ugly URL-encoding or confusion with the equals sign after the parameter name. For your example, this would be something like this for students not in grade 8:

```
GET /students?grade=neq|8
```

Students in grades > 8 would be:

```
GET /students?grade=gt|8
```

Students between grades 8 and 10 (inclusive):

```
GET /students?grade=gte|8,lte|10
```

This approach can be extended to other filterable fields without the need to add additional parameters to modify the way each field is filtered.

Answer (score 6):

Stripe has one of the most respected APIs.

They use a separate parameter for each operator separated with a dot.

For example, to search on created date:

```
/charges?created.gt=
/charges?created.gte=
/charges?created.lt=
/charges?created.lte=
```

In your case you could do something like:

```
/students?grade.gt=8&grade.lt=8
```

Or even add another operator for not:

```
/students?grade.not=8
```