# Negative selection http query string (IS NOT)

Tags: api, http, search, get, query-string

Is it possible to do a `IS NOT` in a http query string, so send IS NOT as an operator in a GET request as query params? 
So something similar to:

```
api/v1/users?firstName!=John&lastName!=Doe
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Thou who searches will find:*

[Here an answer to a question on similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15129949/1697459) that suggests to add an operator param for the field.

```
api/v1/students?firstName=John&firstNameOperator=!%3D&lastName=Doe&lastNameOperator=!%3D
```

The operator field value `!%3D` is [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) `!=`. 
Like this you can send any other operator:

```
!=   -  !%3D
<    -  %3C 
>    -  %3E 
<=   -  %3C%3D 
>=   -  %3E%3D
```