# Filter all products <= 10 quantity in opencart admin panel

Tags: php, opencart

I want to get all product between 1 and 10 quantity in my admin panel
Here's the data in my controller:

```
    $enabled_product = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalNumberOfEnabledProductsWithLessOrEqualTo10Quantity();

    $data['enabled_product'] = $enabled_product;

    $data['enabled_product_link'] = $this->url->link('catalog/product', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&filter_quantity=10&filter_status=1', true);

    $data['enabled_product_link'] = $this->url->link('catalog/product', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&filter_quantity<=10&filter_status=1', true);
```

I'm trying to tell the url that i want all products with quantity <= 10 and status = 1
Here's the url:

```
http://local.loc/admin/index.php?route=catalog/product&token=lNcGHcKRXDz02nQlrw83sRB7UzV4HViz&filter_quantity<=10&filter_status=1
```

The problem is that i can get all products if they are only equal to specific number. I also tried the following url:

```
http://local.loc/admin/index.php?route=catalog/product&token=lNcGHcKRXDz02nQlrw83sRB7UzV4HViz&filter_quantity=10&filter_quantity=9&filter_quantity=8&filter_quantity=7&filter_quantity=6&filter_quantity=5&filter_status=1
```

But did not work. Any ideas how can i get all products with quantity <=10  ?

Comment: Pass the number into one variable and the comparison into another.

Comment: Can you give an example

Comment: What is your OpenCart version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of these methods:

In `admin\model\catalog\product.php`

Find: `$sql .= " AND p.quantity = '" . (int)$data['filter_quantity'] . "'";`

There are two matches.

Change them to: `$sql .= " AND p.quantity <= '" . (int)$data['filter_quantity'] . "'";`

Now this will show all products with quantity 10 or less than 10:

```
http://local.loc/admin/index.php?route=catalog/product&token=lNcGHcKRXDz02nQlrw83sRB7UzV4HViz&filter_quantity=10&filter_status=1
```

**OR**

In `admin\controller\catalog\product.php`

Find: `'filter_quantity' => $filter_quantity,`

Add after: `'filter_quantity_less' => isset($this->request->get['filter_quantity_less']) ? $this->request->get['filter_quantity_less'] : null,`

In `admin\model\catalog\product.php`

Find: `if (isset($data['filter_quantity']) && !is_null($data['filter_quantity'])) {`

There are two matches, add before them:

```
if (isset($data['filter_quantity_less']) && !is_null($data['filter_quantity_less'])) {
    $sql .= " AND p.quantity <= '" . (int)$data['filter_quantity_less'] . "'";
}
```

Now you can use it in url like this:

```
filter_quantity_less=10
```

Answer (score 0):

from a REST perspective you should pass it like that in the url

```
&lesseq=10&filter_status=1
```

where lesseq should be `<=` for the filter_quantity variable however please check [REST URL design for greater than, less than operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614255/rest-url-design-for-greater-than-less-than-operations)
as i believe you can implement exactly the same Answer

Comment: Please give me the whole url. It's not working like this: http://local.loc/admin/index.php?route=catalog/product&token=EWX37Zgm2A6aovmPWwlc2rOMwvtejpuI&filter_quantitylesseq=10&filter_status=1

Comment: this url is wrong , what i meant is somthing like that 'http://local.loc/admin/index.php?route=catalog/product&token=EWX37Zgm2A6aovmPWwlc2rOMwvtejpuI&lesseq=10&filter_status=1'
 and in the controller get the value of $lesseq and assign it to filter_quantity with '<='