# How do I override the equal sign in urllib.parse.urlencode?

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, urlencode

I understand the following is how `urlencode` works.

```
query = {"a": "123", "b": "456"}
encoded_query = urllib.parse.urlencode(query)
#a=123&b=456
```

But what do I do when I need `a=123&b=456&c gt 5`? Is there a way to override the default equal sign?

Comment: No, you can see the options in https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode.

Comment: It's not in fact limitation of `urlencode`. Query strings are designed that way. You can pass `cgt=5` and handle it on the server side. More Info on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614255/rest-url-design-for-greater-than-less-than-operations)

Comment: @venky__ I don't control the REST server-side code. I am writing I am consuming OKTA API'S services.

Comment: from what i understood  from the [docs](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/users/#list-users-with-a-filter) they haven't mentioned anything like your example it's more like `b=456 gt 5`  and not like `b=456&c gt 5`. The earlier one is easier to implement you just pass the whole string "456 gt 5" instead of "456"