# Describing "greater than"-filters search in a REST API URL?

Tags: rest, url, api-design, url-design

I'm designing a REST API where the `/widgets` endpoint can be filtered to only show widgets with a certain number of connections. This seems like a natural design:

```
/widgets?connections=4
```

I also want to allow filtering for widgets using lesser than and greater than, however. These URL designs seem wrong as they don't follow the classic query string pattern or appear misleading:

```
/widgets?connections>2
/widgets?connections=>2
```

What is the normal way of designing this kind of filter? I also need to be able to combine filters, e.g. "more than two connections and exactly one screen".

I've read this related question: [REST URL design for greater than, less than operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614255/rest-url-design-for-greater-than-less-than-operations), but it is not the same as it relates to pagination and ID, and does not contain a neat answer for combined filters.

Answer (score 0):

REST does not give you an exact solution, it just says that your should use standards to build an uniform interface if there are available standards. If not, then it is up to you, anyways it must be documented for the client developers.

Here what you are doing is developing a complete query language for the URI. It would be good to check what exactly you need, because if there is a query language standard, then supporting it completely is just too much work. Afaik. [Odata](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc31360957) has something you need and there are other conventions, for example [RQL](https://github.com/persvr/rql) is a very old one. With a little search there are other ones too: [w](https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/api-design/REST-API-Design-Filtering-Sorting-and-Pagination/) [x](https://api.akeneo.com/documentation/filter.html) [y](https://developer.sas.com/reference/filtering/) [z](https://support.americommerce.com/hc/en-us/articles/202836800-API-Searching-and-Filtering). I guess there are many others too. I would choose one of these and implement only what I need from it or look for an existing implementation.